# Absolute database password recovery

Tags: delphi, c++builder, absolute-db

An old management application for clinic has an absolute database that includes all clients information. we want to fetch all data from absolute database, unfortunately database has password. and the application developer has left long time ago.

is there any way to recover password of Delphi absolute database ?

Comment: @Tong Wang , you have asked the same long time ago. did you have any solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the AbsoluteDB publishers?

Comment: yes, no response from them till now

Comment: file format is .abs , for information about absolute database:http://www.componentace.com/absolute_database_features.htm

Comment: One thing which is not clear from your q is whether anybody is able to access the database at the moment?  Are they?  If not, surely it cannot be only the developer who was able to access it, so why aren't you asking the person who was able most recently to access the db?

Comment: If you have source code of original application then I suggest you check it as it probably contains password somewhere in it. If the password is not stored directly in code but read from some configuration file the code will also tell you from where. But if you don't have source code of original application then it is questionable if you are even eligible to access the data that is stored in the database.  Maybe you acquired database illegally and are now asking us for helping you crack the code? Probably a small possibility but it is still possibility.

Comment: i had the exe application written in delphi, but not the source code, i tried to decompile it by some tools but it give me the assembly. application is using the Data.abs database file. the application has also thumbs.db which has the png files of the application, i think password is embedded inside the application. what i need exactly is all the customer data inside the database. currently we are writing it one by one to excel from the application view as it dosent have an export functionality or even copy paste.

Comment: so from the application view, we are moving 11k clients one by one to excel file. is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

i have solved my issue :) 
You can look at exe binary code to find string that could be used as a password.
using OllyDbg (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OllyDbg) i have found the password string embbeded in exe file.